# Qgis 1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 constant crashes as soon as I try to do anything

Tags: qgis, vector

I can get a google earth physical layer open but as soon as I try to open a vector file it crashes-just goes away-no error message, nothing

Comment: QGIS 1.9 is not a current stable release only 1.8.0.1 is http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download

Comment: If you launch QGIS from the terminal, it will output text-based warnings and error messages to the terminal screen that the GUI generally ignores, that you can study after a crash. Which might give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: What is the source of your vector file?  Is it a particular type, like a shapefile or geodatabase layer, or all vector layers?  Is the same happening with Raster?  The more detail you provide, the higher the likelihood that someone will be able to help you.